# Comment parler de l'« enseignement non universitaire »

Tags: choix-de-mot

Je cherche un mot ou une tournure pour parler globalement de l'enseignement en dehors de l'université. Plus précisément, lors d'une présentation, je voudrais inclure une diapositive qui serait :

### Expérience d'enseignement (Titre)

## Universitaire

1. Université de nulle part
2. University of nowhere
3. Universität von nirgendwo

## Mot/expression pour désigner l'enseignement non universitaire

1. Cours particulier en classe et à domicile (système équivalant du système français...)
2. Tuteur
3. Professeur secondaire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le plus simple est d'utiliser ***autre*** :

> Expérience d'enseignement
>
> - Universitaire
>
>   1. ...
>   2. ...
>   3. ...
> - Autre
>
>   1. Cours particuliers en classe et à domicile
>   2. ...
>   3. Professeur dans le secondaire

Comment: Un grand merci ;c'est exactement ce que j'ai cherché ; juste une question les tournures enseignement dehors université ou bien enseignement non universitaire sont correctes ?

Comment: Seul le deuxième est correct comme l'était aussi *non universitaire*. Le premier pourrait être *enseignement en dehors de l'université* mais il vaudrait mieux écrire *enseignement hors-université*.

Answer (score 1):

Un terme qui convient bien est  « **extra-universitaire** ».

> (TLFi) A. Extra- marque l'extériorité.
>   b) L'adj. renvoie à un subst. exprimant une activité soc. ou intellectuelle :
>
> - extra-universitaire.
> - Une revue extra-universitaire
> - L'enseignement universitaire et surtout les enseignements extra- ou post-universitaires aident le professeur à se maintenir dans l'univers de la communication .